# Is the calculation of weight to be suspended inorder to produce electricity from an alternator correct or not?

Tags: torque, alternator

I bought a alternator with the following specs:
power: 5 hp
rpm: 1800
voltage: 220V

The formula for finding the horsepower is:

horsepower= (RPM X Torque)/5252

By substituting the value of horsepower and RPM (as provided) in the above formula i got

Torque= 14.5 N-m

suppose that a wheel is connected to the rotor of the alternator such that when the weight is suspended on the wheel it makes it rotate.
Let us assume that the radius of the wheel is 50 cm.
Now we have,

Torque = (R)(F) sine(theta)

=> 14.5 = (0.5)(F)(1)

hence the force comes out to be 29 N

and now we can calculate the weight as

29/9.8 = 2.9 Kg

So i just want to ask whether suspending a 3 kg weight to the wheel generate 220 V electricity?
I have also seen that if any load is attached to the alternator the torque required to rotate the rotor also increases but i do not know whether the formula stated above by me consider it or not?
Please guide me.

Comment: You will get 220 volts at the full running speed.

Comment: A [gravity battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_battery) is a real thing. Check out commercial efforts such as [Energy Vault](https://energyvault.com/) and [Gravitricity](https://www.gravitricity.com/).

Comment: Work out the velocity you need the weight to fall, to get 5 kW. Add that to the question. What height do you have available for the falling weight?

Comment: Torque is 14.5 ft lbs  or 20 Nm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. *but* only so long as the 50cm wheel is maintaining 1800 RPM.

Given that the circumference of the wheel is 1.57m, that means you have to unspool 2.8 kilometers of massless rope with the weight on the end of it every minute to achieve that. The weight will be travelling downwards at 105 miles an hour.

Comment: So all the OP has to do is mount the alternator 2.8km above the ground :) and that's for only 1 minute...

Comment: If a gearbox is installed will it drop speed of rope with which it has to drop.

Comment: Yes. If the gearbox is 100:1 it'll drop the speed by 100, but you now have a 290kg weight (plus some to overcome losses in the gearbox. Say, a small car), and you need very strong rope.

Comment: @Brian Drummond suppose we use three gears inorder to achieve the ratio of 100:1 then also will we be needing the 290 kg weight?

Comment: Of course you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can short-circuit a lot of the tedious detail by using the conservation of energy.

A 29 N = 2.9 kg weight will release 29 Joules, 29 watt.seconds, for each metre that it falls.

5 hp is about 5*750 = 3750 watts.

This means that your weight falling through 1 m would power the fully-loaded generator for about 7.7 ms, assuming 100% efficiency, or 4 ms assuming a more reasonable 50%. So to maintain full output, the rope would have to travel at 250 m/s, not far short of the speed of sound.

You could get more reasonable speeds with larger weights. One tonne is about 10 kN. That would need to move downwards at just a shade less than 1 m/s for full 5 hp output.

Now that you have some forces and speeds, it's just a matter of suitable pully sizes to match the rope speed to the generator speed.

Comment: If a gearbox is installed will it drop speed of rope with which it has to drop.

Comment: You choose the pulley sizes and gearbox ratio to match the speed of rope drop and the generator RPM. The point of the energy conservation calculation is to find out what the minimum weight*speed product is to get the requisite power, before going through the pulley/gearbox calculations.

Comment: Can you please explain the above statement with some example or provide any article for reference.

Comment: No. If you don't understand it, then you have to take a few steps back and try something simpler, or work through the sums yourself, many many times, to get a feel for what's going on. An understanding of energy conservation is what comes when you've flogged through many specific cases yourself, and then see the generalisation. If you want energy out, you need to put energy in. The height*force product is energy, no amount of gearing will change that. Note that choosing a different weight and a different height drop is a form of 'gearing'.